# Create a new thread in click button event c++

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli

I have create a gui using windows form application. I am using a button which perform some function on click event. I have noticed that the gui form freezes when the functionality of button take place. I came across with some libraries for multithreading. However I am trying to understand what should I  add in a new thread. Which library should I use? My onClick event are:

```
    private: System::Void button1_Click_1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerAsync( 10 );                    
     }
    private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {              
             this->progressBar1 ->Value = 0;
             string path = "vid/frames/";
             this->timer1->Start();
             Detection detect;
             vector<string> files = detect.listFile(path);
             for(int index=0; index<files.size(); index++){
                 cout << files.at(index) <<endl;
                 detect.draw(path, files.at(index), modulator, trackbar_values);
                 this->progressBar1->Increment(1);
             }
         }
```

It runs one time doWork and it stops.

Comment: Use the BackgroundWorker class to make this easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a **BackgroundWorker** component. See the documentation link here : [BackgroundWorker class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2).

In your button event, call RunWorkerAsync method. When RunWorkerAsync is called, the event `DoWork` is raise

```
void backgroundWorker1_DoWork( Object^ sender, DoWorkEventArgs^ e )
{
}
```

Put your code in.

Comment: Ok I have create a backgroundWorker using the toolbox which creates the function dowork. What should I add in button code?

Comment: you shoud call RunWorkerAsync

Comment: I add  backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerAsync( 10 ); however the form still freezes during the functionality.

Comment: Put the rest of code in DoWork event, your button must have 1 line.

Comment: Ok I did so, now I have lost the  function of the button. I copy the code to doWork function and I left only runworkerAsync onclick function

Comment: Basically it runs one time in for-loop and stops.